# error: Iso c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [c++]

Tags: c++, function, pointers, codeblocks

I'm getting the error in title when trying to compile.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int chance()
{
return rand()%11;
}

int main()
{
if (chance > 5)
    cout << "You win." << endl;
else
    cout << "You lose." << endl;
return 0;
}
```

This is my full code, I'm attempting to have it output You win or You lose, 50-50

Comment: use `srand()` function

Comment: rand() % 11 will give you a value of 0,1,2, ..., 10, i.e. 11 different values. For 0,1,2, ..., 5 (6 different values) you print "You lose." For 6,7, ..., 10 (5 values) you print "You win." That is not 50-50.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing `function pointer` to an `integer(5)`, I guess you want to call `chance()` function, try

```
if (chance() > 5)
          ^^
```